# iframe not rendering in ipython-notebook

Tags: python, iframe, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The following iframe will not render in an ipython-notebook

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('<iframe src=http://stackoverflow.com width=700 height=350></iframe>')
```

but, this one will render (note, .com versus .org)

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('<iframe src=http://stackoverflow.org width=700 height=350></iframe>')
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in the first example? If this is a bug, where do I submit a bug report?

Comment: Maybe using the IFrame object from IPython display would work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." in javascript console. Some sites explicitly refuse to be displayed in iframes.

Answer (score 40):

IPython now supports IFrame directly:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame('http://stackoverflow.org', width=700, height=350)
```

For more on IPython embeds check out this [IPython notebook.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb)

Comment: The link [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) is similar to the one that looks to have been originally linked.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get some iframes to embed on my notebook server by modifying the url to use https:

```
from IPython.display import VimeoVideo
v = VimeoVideo(id='53051817', width=800, height=600)
print v.src
>>> 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/53051817'
v.src = v.src.replace('http','https')
v
```

Answer (score 1):

use `%%html` magic cell command:

```py
%%html
<iframe width="700" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r0Ogt-q956I" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```