# Visualizing a TensorFlow graph in Jupyter doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, ipython, jupyter, graph-visualization, tensorboard

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter) about how to visualise a tensorflow graph in Jupyter notebook. I found that this answer comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter) example with just one modification in (`tensor.tensor_content = bytes("<stripped %d bytes>"%size, 'utf-8')` is replaced by `tensor.tensor_content = "<stripped %d bytes>"%size`). However if I try to rerun it on `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` the visualisation doesn't work: the iframe is white and there is no nodes displayed.

I would highly appreciate if you explain me what I am doing wrong. Here there is a simple example to reproduce the problem.

Import:

```py
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display, HTML
```

Create graph:

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 25, 25, 3], name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1, name='y_true_cls')

print graph.get_operations()
```

The output:

```
[<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x115902850>,
 <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x115902690>,
 <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x115902b10>,
 <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x1159029d0>]
```

The visualisation functions:

```py
def strip_consts(graph_def, max_const_size=32):
    """Strip large constant values from graph_def."""
    strip_def = tf.GraphDef()
    for n0 in graph_def.node:
        n = strip_def.node.add() 
        n.MergeFrom(n0)
        if n.op == 'Const':
            tensor = n.attr['value'].tensor
            size = len(tensor.tensor_content)
            if size > max_const_size:
                tensor.tensor_content = bytes("<stripped %d bytes>"%size, "utf-8")
    return strip_def

def show_graph(graph_def, max_const_size=32):
    """Visualize TensorFlow graph."""
    if hasattr(graph_def, 'as_graph_def'):
        graph_def = graph_def.as_graph_def()
    strip_def = strip_consts(graph_def, max_const_size=max_const_size)
    code = """
        <script>
          function load() {{
            document.getElementById("{id}").pbtxt = {data};
          }}
        </script>
        <link rel="import" href="https://tensorboard.appspot.com/tf-graph-basic.build.html" onload=load()>
        <div style="height:600px">
          <tf-graph-basic id="{id}"></tf-graph-basic>
        </div>
    """.format(data=repr(str(strip_def)), id='graph'+str(np.random.rand()))

    iframe = """
        <iframe seamless style="width:1200px;height:620px;border:0" srcdoc="{}"></iframe>
    """.format(code.replace('"', '&quot;'))
    display(HTML(iframe))
```

The result:

[image]

**UPD** I tried a simpler example:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.ones((), name="x")
y = tf.ones((), name="y")
z = tf.add(x, y, name="z")
show_graph()
```

But it still doesn't work. I suspect the problem is related to Javascript/HTML code that is generated:

```
    <script>
      function load() {
        document.getElementById(&quot;graph0.746875762596&quot;).pbtxt = 'node {\n  name: &quot;x&quot;\n  op: &quot;Const&quot;\n  attr {\n    key: &quot;dtype&quot;\n    value {\n      type: DT_FLOAT\n    }\n  }\n  attr {\n    key: &quot;value&quot;\n    value {\n      tensor {\n        dtype: DT_FLOAT\n        tensor_shape {\n        }\n        float_val: 1.0\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nnode {\n  name: &quot;y&quot;\n  op: &quot;Const&quot;\n  attr {\n    key: &quot;dtype&quot;\n    value {\n      type: DT_FLOAT\n    }\n  }\n  attr {\n    key: &quot;value&quot;\n    value {\n      tensor {\n        dtype: DT_FLOAT\n        tensor_shape {\n        }\n        float_val: 1.0\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nnode {\n  name: &quot;z&quot;\n  op: &quot;Add&quot;\n  input: &quot;x&quot;\n  input: &quot;y&quot;\n  attr {\n    key: &quot;T&quot;\n    value {\n      type: DT_FLOAT\n    }\n  }\n}\n';
      }
    </script>
    <link rel=&quot;import&quot; href=&quot;https://tensorboard.appspot.com/tf-graph-basic.build.html&quot; onload=load()>
    <div style=&quot;height:600px&quot;>
      <tf-graph-basic id=&quot;graph0.746875762596&quot;></tf-graph-basic>
    </div>
```

Maybe something with `&quot` and `'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason behind the failure is imports (`<link rel="import" ...`) are [only supported under Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) failing in [Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/mozilla-and-web-components/) and Safari, and there's no sight to be adopted by others until WebComponents definition arrives. So, you'd better run Jupyter in Chrome.

If you're against Chrome, there's good news. You can use a Polyfill (a piece of code that implements a feature on web browsers that do not support the feature) to make it work:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
```

I've tested it in Firefox and Safari and it works, but not perfectly fine. It is a little bit slower to load the Polypill and the graph canvas is reduced to one inch wide (I don't know why, TensorBoard internals). Then I realised `platform.js` has been [deprecated](http://webcomponents.org/articles/platformjs-becomes-webcomponentsjs/) but new implementations incorporates new errors (unhandled events and XML parsing).

Following is the modified code:

```
# TensorFlow Graph visualizer code
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display, HTML

def strip_consts(graph_def, max_const_size=32):
    """Strip large constant values from graph_def."""
    strip_def = tf.GraphDef()
    for n0 in graph_def.node:
        n = strip_def.node.add() 
        n.MergeFrom(n0)
        if n.op == 'Const':
            tensor = n.attr['value'].tensor
            size = len(tensor.tensor_content)
            if size > max_const_size:
                tensor.tensor_content = "<stripped %d bytes>"%size
    return strip_def

def show_graph(graph_def, max_const_size=32):
    """Visualize TensorFlow graph."""
    if hasattr(graph_def, 'as_graph_def'):
        graph_def = graph_def.as_graph_def()
    strip_def = strip_consts(graph_def, max_const_size=max_const_size)
    code = """
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
        <script>
          function load() {{
            document.getElementById("{id}").pbtxt = {data};
          }}
        </script>
        <link rel="import" href="https://tensorboard.appspot.com/tf-graph-basic.build.html" onload=load()>
        <div style="height:600px">
          <tf-graph-basic id="{id}"></tf-graph-basic>
        </div>
    """.format(data=repr(str(strip_def)), id='graph'+str(np.random.rand()))

    iframe = """
        <iframe seamless style="width:1200px;height:620px;border:0" srcdoc="{}"></iframe>
    """.format(code.replace('"', '&quot;'))
    display(HTML(iframe))
```

Notice there's only one line added at the beginning of the `code = """` block. It must be there because it's required by the Polyfill.

Original source code can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb). You can ask him to evolve it within Google to cover other browsers than Chrome, but I don't think it will happen.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. It is almost there there! There is a problem with one svg: <svg id="svg" class="style-scope tf-graph-scene" width="60" height="69.16583251953125"> Its width is very small.. I guess it is possible to increase it with js?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version I'm using [right now](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/97504b8221a8529e7a51a50915206d68)

You should be able to do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! It still doesn't work. Do you have any idea what can be a reason? I use anaconda for python 2.7. Yesterday I updated it together with tensorflow and all other packages.

Comment: maybe there's something in Jupyter preventing external page from getting loaded? You could try to modify `show_graph` to save the page it generates to standalone html and open that

Comment: If I download "DeapDreaming with Tensorflow" and render it with Jupyter, the graph is not rendered. However, it does render with nbviewer. I also checked that I can embed `iframe`, e.g. from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619964/iframe-not-rendering-in-ipython-notebook . I guess the problem maybe with the javascript function? Could you please take a look? I updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like jupyter issue, maybe your version doesn't want to display iframe with external dependencies for security reasons?

Comment: OK in Chrome it does render. That is also may be related to Firefox. I checked in its console, it doesn't complain about security... Hmmmm