# Display Plotly HTML inside a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a `.html` file created as

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.write_html("px.html", full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

I can open this file from the filesystem and it displays fine in Chrome.

What I need to do, however, is read this file into a Jupyter Notebook and display it.

I am trying the following in a Notebook cell

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(filename="px.html"))
```

This gives an error in the notebook of

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

The Chrome Javascript console shows

[image]

How do I get this plotly html to display from the file in the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for my in JupyterLab and classic Jupyter Notebook, based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512364/8508004).

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame('px.html', width=700, height=350)
```